# Making PWM with analog input control in PIC18F4550

Tags: microcontroller, pic, pwm, duty-cycle, xc8

I am trying to program with the PIC18F4550 a PWM with which I can regulate the duty-cycle with a variable resistance.

I attach my code to explain the problem I have.

```
#pragma config CPUDIV = OSC1_PLL2
#pragma config USBDIV = 1 
#pragma config FOSC = HS        
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF      
#pragma config IESO = OFF   
#pragma config PWRT = OFF       
#pragma config BOR = OFF        
#pragma config BORV = 3         
#pragma config VREGEN = OFF  
#pragma config WDT = OFF        
#pragma config WDTPS = 32768    
#pragma config CCP2MX = ON      
#pragma config PBADEN = ON      
#pragma config LPT1OSC = OFF    
#pragma config MCLRE = ON       
#pragma config STVREN = ON      
#pragma config LVP = ON         
#pragma config ICPRT = OFF      
#pragma config XINST = OFF      
#pragma config CP0 = OFF        
#pragma config CP1 = OFF       
#pragma config CP2 = OFF        
#pragma config CP3 = OFF    
#pragma config CPB = OFF        
#pragma config CPD = OFF        
#pragma config WRT0 = OFF       
#pragma config WRT1 = OFF       
#pragma config WRT2 = OFF       
#pragma config WRT3 = OFF   
#pragma config WRTC = OFF       
#pragma config WRTB = OFF       
#pragma config WRTD = OFF       
#pragma config EBTR0 = OFF      
#pragma config EBTR1 = OFF      
#pragma config EBTR2 = OFF      
#pragma config EBTR3 = OFF     
#pragma config EBTRB = OFF

#include <xc.h>

#define _XTAL_FREQ 20000000L

void ADC_Initialize()
{
    ADCON1bits.PCFG = 0;
    ADCON1bits.VCFG = 0;
    ADCON0 = 0;
    ADCON2bits.ACQT = 3;
    ADCON2bits.ADCS = 5;
    ADCON2bits.ADFM = 1;
    ADCON0bits.ADON = 1;
}

unsigned int ADC_Read(unsigned char channel)
{
  ADCON0 &= 0x11000101;
  ADCON0 |= channel<<3;
  __delay_ms(2);
  GO_nDONE = 1;
  while(GO_nDONE);
  return ((ADRESH<<8)+ADRESL);
}

#define TMR2PRESCALE 16
long PWM_freq = 8000;

void PWM_Initialize()
{
    PR2 = 0x26;
    CCPR1L = 1;
    TRISCbits.RC1 = 0;
    TRISCbits.RC2 = 0;
    T2CON = 0x03;   
    CCP1CON = 0x0C;
    TMR2 = 0;
    T2CONbits.TMR2ON = 1; 
}

void PWM_Duty(unsigned int duty)
{
  if(duty<1023)
  {
    duty = ((float)duty/1023)*(_XTAL_FREQ/(PWM_freq*TMR2PRESCALE));

    CCPR1L = duty>>2;
  }
}

void main()
{
  int adc_value;  
  TRISC = 0; 
  TRISA = 1; 
  TRISD = 0; 
  ADC_Initialize(); 
  PWM_Initialize(); 

  do
  {
    adc_value = ADC_Read(4);
    PWM_Duty(adc_value);    
    __delay_ms(50);       
  }while(1);
}
```

If I execute the above code, what I have at the output of the PWM are 0v and a frequency 0.
As shown in the following image

[image]

If in the fixed code the value of the PWM Duty (580), for example.

Then I stop running the analog input.

So it seems that the PWM signal is regulated and I have a voltage at the output.

As I show in the following image.

[image]

What I do not understand is that in neither of the 2 cases the frequency is 0, when it should be approximately 8000Hz.

On the other hand I see that if I set the duty_cycle it seems that it regulates and gives voltage to the output.

So there must be a fault in the part of the analog input that I have not been able to find.

Finally, I leave a picture of the circuit.

[image]

Comment: `PR = 0x26` that don't make any sense for me. Another case: Why the cast to `float`?

Comment: Is the result of the calculation:                                                                              
PWM periodo = (PR2 + 1)*4*Tosc*Prescaler ->
1/8KHz = (PR2 + 1)*4*(1/20MHZ)*16 ->
PR2 + 1 = 39.06 ->
PR2 = 38.06 = 38 -> 26 hex -> PR = 0x26

Comment: I have tried with the parameter PR2 = 0x3FF and the same thing happens

Comment: `duty = ((float)duty/1023)*(_XTAL_FREQ/(PWM_freq*TMR2PRESCALE));` This part is also wrong. Just `CCPR1L = duty>>2;`.Have a look into the datasheet.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have already got it working.
Apart from the errors mentioned above I also found this ADC_Read (0).

Comment: Great. Maybe make an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following code I could make it work

```
#define TMR2PRESCALE 16
long PWM_freq = 8000;

void PWM_Initialize() 
{
   PR2 = ("%#x", (_XTAL_FREQ/(PWM_freq*4*TMR2PRESCALE)) - 1); //Setting the PR2 formulae using Datasheet 
   CCPR1L = 0x1F;
   TRISCbits.RC1 = 0; 
   TRISCbits.RC2 = 0;
   T2CON = 0x03;   
   CCP1CON = 0x0C;
   TMR2 = 0;
   T2CONbits.TMR2ON = 1; 
}

void PWM_Duty(unsigned int duty)
{
  if(duty < 1023)
  {
      duty = ((float)duty/1023)*(_XTAL_FREQ/(PWM_freq*TMR2PRESCALE));
      CCPR1L = duty>>2;
  }
}

void ADC_Initialize()
{    
   ADCON1bits.PCFG = 0;
   ADCON1bits.VCFG = 0;
   ADCON0 = 0;
   ADCON2bits.ACQT = 3;
   ADCON2bits.ADCS = 5;
   ADCON2bits.ADFM = 1;
   ADCON0bits.ADON = 1;
}

unsigned int ADC_Read(unsigned char ch)
{
   if(ch > 13)return 0;
   ADCON0 = 0;
   ADCON0 = (ch<<2);
   ADCON0bits.ADON = 1;
   ADCON0bits.GO_DONE = 1;
   while(ADCON0bits.GO_DONE == 1);
   ADCON0bits.ADON = 0;
   return ADRES;
}

void main()
{    
   int adc_value;  
   TRISC = 0;
   TRISA = 1;
   TRISD = 0; 
   ADC_Initialize();
   PWM_Initialize();

   do
   {
       adc_value = ADC_Read(0);
       PWM_Duty(adc_value);    
       __delay_ms(50);       
   }
   while(1); //Infinite Loop  
}
```